# My code does not proceed after Thread().start()

Tags: python, multithreading, debugging, pygame

I am writing a code for battleship game and I'm kind of stuck.

Here is a part of my code

```
color_change()
ship_position()

Thread(target=ship_pos_Recv()).start()
ships_send = pickle.dumps(ships)
client.send(ships_send)
print('sent')
Lock(target=ship_pos_Recv()).acquire()

# main loop begins
```

`color_change()` 'colors' the cells on the grid and `ship_position()` allows the user to place his/her ships.

Problem is, the code does not proceed after `Thread(target=ship_pos_Recv()).start()`; it won't perform the pickle function.
`ship_pos_Recv()` looks like this:

```
def ship_pos_Recv():
    global enemy_ships
    incoming = client.recv(2048)
    converted = pickle.loads(incoming)
    enemy_ships = converted
```

Why doesn't it 'go beyond' the thread part? I know my explanation is poor here, leave me a comment and I'll try my best to answer your inquiries.

PLZ HAAALP

Comment: don't call your function , change your code to , `Thread(target=ship_pos_Recv).start()`

Answer (score 0):

As you have it right now, you are calling the function `ship_pos_Recv` and then passing it's return to the `target` parameter in the `Thread` class. If you look into the `Thread` class, you can see it calls the function you pass to target (in the `run` method).

What the code should look like is:

```
Thread(target=ship_pos_Recv).start()
```

This would pass `ship_pos_Recv` to the `Thread` class to then run as a thread.

As far as `Lock`, it doesn't look like that's being used correctly. If you're trying to wait for the thread to complete, then you should set the thread to a variable and then `join` to it. Example:

```
t = Thread(target=ship_pos_Recv)
t.start()
# do some code
t.join()  # this waits for the thread to complete
```